# Why do I need a UNIQUE constraint on a column if my application already validates the data before saving it?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, unique

UNIQUE is an index which makes your field, well, unique. But is it worth using it if you're already doing your validation in PHP prior to inserting new data? An extra INDEX isn't the end of the world but if you're after query optimization then UNIQUE just gets in the way, right?

Comment: Stop trying to "optimize". The database should *encode* the relational model and integrity constraints, as best it can. If a column should be unique, make it unique. While access code "should be well behaved" (good luck never having a silly bug), do not forgo making it part of the schema! (Unlike more strict schemas - e.g. triggers for business rules or only-sp-access - this is effectively a minimal-cost "freebie", just like fk constraints.)

Comment: What happens if there's a need to add/update data from somewhere other than your PHP application? Will that method know that it should do the same exact validation? The database constraints will for sure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why wear a seat belt if you're a good driver and you can save two seconds of your total trip time?

**One of the most important lessons for a programmer to learn is that he is human and he makes mistakes.**  Worse, everyone else working on this code is human, too.

Why does the UNIQUE constraint exist?  To protect the database from humans making mistakes.  Turning off your UNIQUE constraint says "You do not need to worry, Mr. Database, I will never give you data that doesn't match my intent."

What if something happens to your code such that your validation for uniqueness breaks?  Now your code dumps duplicate records into the database.  But if you had a UNIQUE constraint on that column, when your front-end code stopped working, you'd get your queries blowing up.

You're human.  Accept it.  Let the computer do its job and help protect you from yourself.

Comment: Another reason (that is not to be underestimated) for having as much declrative constraints in the database as possible: it *documents* your database. Anyone looking at the database for the first time immediately knows what rules apply to the data - without wading through the code.

Answer (score 5):

UNIQUE is not only for making sure data is valid. The primary purpose is to optimize queries: if the database knows the field is unique, it can stop searching for hits as soon as the first record is found. You can't pass that information to the database through well-crafted queries alone.

Answer (score 4):

That is an interesting question.

- Are you sure that there is no way for your code to be bypassed ?
- Are you sure nothing else will ever access the data beside the PHP application ?
- Are you sure the rest of your application won't fail in the case where a duplicate is inserted ?
- What would be the implication of having duplicate entries, would that cause problem for future references or calculations ?

This is some of the questions that constraint at database level help solve.

As for optimization, a constraint does not make the process of retrieving data noticeably slower and it can in fact be use in the execution plan at some point, since it is related to an index.

So no, it won't get in the way of optimization and it will also protect your data from inconsistencies.

Comment: The above is pretty much true for *any* database constraint.

Answer (score 3):

As pst mentions, at this stage in your development, you are in no position to begin optimizing your database or the application in question.

It's generally not a *bad* thing to add additional **sanity checks** in your system. Yes, you're hurting performance just that tiny little bit, but in no way will any user ever notice an extra CPU tick or two.

Think about this: Today you do your validation in php, but do not assert uniqueness in the database. In the future, you, a colleague, or some other guy who has forked your project changes the original php validation, ruins it, or forgets it altogether. At this point, you'll probably wish you had that added check in your database.

Answer (score 0):

tl:dr; **Transactional Integrity** (in the database) handles **Race Conditions** (in the application).

The *Concurrency and integrity* section of [these Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html) explains why this is necessary with an example scenario.

Databases with transactional integrity guarantee uniqueness through [isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29), while applications actually take a few separate steps (get the value, check if there are other values, then save the value) outside of transactional isolation that leave them vulnerable to [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), especially at scale.